# Altering user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I run this code:

```
item_type = input("Enter item type")
def item_name_redefined():
        if item_type == "apple" or "apples":
            return "apples"
        elif item_type == "banana" or "bananas":
            return "bananas"
        else:
            print("Item not found!")
print(item_name_redefined())
```

Whenever I run this code it either sets the if statement to true and only returns apples or in some cases it only returns "None." Does anyone know why, and if you could help, that would be great!

Thanks,
~Jack

Comment: Your program won't compile. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going wrong here:

1. There is a syntax error on lines 4 and 6 because of a missing colon. This code should never execute at all, as you have written it here.
2. On the last line, you are printing the function itself, not its return value, because you aren't calling it.
3. When testing for equality you first evaluate `item_type == "apples"` and then `or "apples"`. The latter part of this expression is always truthy, so this function will always return `"apples"`.
4. `item_type` is always being hard coded to the string `"Enter item type"`. I take it you intended to display a prompt for user input, but that is never happening.

Try this:

```
item_type_prompt = "Enter item type: "


def item_name_redefined():
    item_type = input(item_type_prompt)

    if item_type == "apple" or item_type == "apples":
        return "apples"
    elif item_type == "banana" or item_type == "bananas":
        return "bananas"
    else:
        return "Item not found!"


print(item_name_redefined())
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not getting user input. First line of your code should be changed to this

```
item_type = input("Enter item type")
```

Also put the `:` at the end of line 4 and 6

Answer (score 0):

The above code will always return apples
because the condition provided to the if statement

`if item_type == "apple" or "apples":`

> will evaluate item_type == 'apple' which  if true will return apples
>   and if not the second operand "apples" has a truthy value of True.
>   This will lead to execution of if statement in all cases.

Instead write  `if item_type == "apple" or item_type == "apples":`

> Perform same changes for elif condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
item_type = input("Enter item type: ")

def item_name_redefined():
  global item_type
  if item_type == "apple" or item_type == "apples":
      return "apples"
  elif item_type == "banana" or item_type == "bananas":
        return "bananas"
  else: 
        print("Item not found!")

print(item_name_redefined())
```

Comment: Why have you used `global item_type` when `item_type` is defined in the parent scope anyway

Comment: In case if you want to update value of item_type variable if it isnt global than you wont be able to update it